# jsf Life Cycle:storing component tree and form value in Restore View

Tags: jsf-2

How can I see what is saving in ui component tree in restore view phase? Where does form values(like form input field value) are saved in restore view phase? And how ui component tree extract them and validate them before storing to a model object?

Answer (score 5):

> *How can I see what is saving in ui component tree in restore view phase?*

This question is ultimately confusing. There's nothing being *saved* during *restore*. Instead, the state is being *restored*. The save of the state happens during render response phase. You can see it happen in the `saveView()` method of the JSF-implementation specific implementation of `StateManager`. In case of Mojarra, it's [`StateManagerImpl#saveView()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/application/StateManagerImpl.java#StateManagerImpl.saveView%28com.sun.faces.application.FacesContext%29).

---

> *Where does form values(like form input field value) are saved in restore view phase?*

The view state does not contain any form values. The submitted values are just obtained as HTTP request parameters the usual way during apply request values phase. If you're familiar with basic [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) API, you surely understand how that works.

---

> *And how ui component tree extract them and validate them before storing to a model object?*

Extracting (decoding) the form values happens during apply request values phase roughly like follows:

```
String submittedValue = request.getParameter(input.getClientId(facesContext));
```

The source code for this can in Mojarra be seen in [`HtmlBasicRenderer#decode()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/HtmlBasicRenderer.java#HtmlBasicRenderer.decode%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29). Validating happens in [`UIInput#validate()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java#UIInput.validate%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method during validations phase which can roughly be represented as follows:

```
for (Validator validator : input.getValidators())
    validator.validate(facesContext, input, submittedAndConvertedValue);
}
```

#### See also:

- [JSF lifecycle/phases cheatsheet](https://jsf.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz#block_1484)

Comment: I am trying to say in my first question is that how component tree is generated that represent the webpage? I followed your reference.It is a very good resource. But I am having problem understanding the viewId. Does the viewId represent the root of the requested page?

Comment: I start to get more confused what exactly you're trying to ask/say there. Aren't you confusing "JSF component tree" with "JSF view state"? They are not the same. As to the view ID, it's basically the unique path to the XHTML file like so `/page.xhtml`, which is extracted from the request URI.

Comment: yes I am confused between "JSF Component tree" amd "jSF view state".I could not find any difference. I found an article http://palkonyves.blogspot.com/2013/08/demistifying-jsf-21-lifecycle-mojarra.html. In that I think thery are trying to say that saved view state is used to create the component tree.

Comment: I am going to get the crap that it's inaccurate, but at least It gives some ideas :) - the author of that article